# Large angular app: requirejs or standalone angular apps?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Our angularjs app becomes bigger and bigger. Lots of modules and up to 10MB js libraries loaded when the app starts. 
What the best practice to resolve this? Requirejs or separate it to several standalone angular apps?

Comment: any help at all? http://briantford.com/blog/huuuuuge-angular-apps

Answer (score 0):

Requirejs will help you organize, but 10 megs of static javascript do not sound like an organization problem only.

If breaking down into separate apps makes sense for you (i.e. various distinct functionalities housed under the same roof), it could also help you shrink down on javascript statics the client has to load (assuming one part of the site does not request js files it doesn't need) by only including the required js files.

With requirejs however you will enjoy a more structured development time, and you could opt to use the files unpackaged or optimized (r.js optimizer)- but lazy loading (http requiring) unpackaged modules could hurt perceived website performance more than the all-in-one-min.js

If you can put in the time for optimizing require builds, you could try [dehydration](http://calendar.perfplanet.com/2011/lazy-evaluation-of-commonjs-modules/) or split packaging to help speed up your app(s)